# Increment id value in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#cc").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#cc iframe").attr("src", $("#cc iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

I would like to apply that to 10 different divs in my markup (`#cc-1`, `#cc-2`, `#cc-3`, etc...).

I tried using a `for` loop so I don't have to rewrite the same code 10 times by doing the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    $('"#cc-' + i + ' iframe"').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('"#cc-' + i + ' iframe"').attr("src", $('"#cc-' + i + 'iframe"').attr("src"));
    });

}
```

The thing is, I don't know how to concatenate the variable `i` inside my jQuery selector with everything else.

Please note that I need to target the `iframe` inside every `#cc-` div. This is the part what I'm getting trouble with. When adding the `iframe` after the concatenation of the `#cc-` with the variable `i` I get a syntax error.

I hope I made myself clear. Any clues in what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why the double quotes everywhere in your second example, they are creating invalid selectors. `$('#cc-' + i + ' iframe')`

Comment: I tried without double quotes `$('#cc-' + i + ' iframe');` and got no luck either. :(

Comment: honestly it would be much easier to add a dummy css class to your html tags and attaching you handlers to that class via jQuery

Comment: Is not possible by the nature of what I'm trying to do... By doing so the functionality I need wouldn't be possible. That's why I need those separated ids.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read the `src` of an element and set that as the `src` of the same element. Surely you want a different element?

Comment: There's also an unrelated issue with variable scoping. All the handler functions share the same declaration of `i`. By the time any of them run, `i === 11`, so it will have no effect if there is no `#cc-11` element. (Or if there is, it will try to change that element when any of the others from 1 to 10 fires an event.) Writing `let i = 1` would work if you could trust the client to have the latest javascript. Otherwise: `for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { (function() { var j = i; $('#cc-' + j + ' iframe').... })(); }`, replacing `i` with `j` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks @David Knipe, you were right in both of your statements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate a variable in a selector like you are doing, however you don't need to add quotations.

**Change this:**

```
 $('"#cc-' + i + ' iframe"')
```

**To this:**

```
 $('#cc-' + i + ' iframe')
```

Also you are forgetting to add a space infront of your `iframe` class.

**Change this:**

```
$('"#cc-' + i + 'iframe"')
```

**To This:**

```
$('#cc-' + i + ' iframe')
```

**Complete Change:**

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    $('#cc-' + i + ' iframe').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#cc-' + i + ' iframe').attr("src", $('#cc-' + i + ' iframe').attr("src"));
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried that before and indeed the console doesn't returns any syntax error.

However when trying to see what do I get when doing `console.log` to that expression (`$('#cc-' + i + ' iframe')`) I get the following text:

`[iframe, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`

Well, what I wanted to know was how to properly concatenate the variable with the other stuff. I guess this solves it.

Comment: @LuisCarlosPando From my understanding there is no special logic to concatenating a variable to a selector, except maybe if the variable contains special characters that would break the query. You just got to make sure the string is outputting a valid query

Comment: @LuisCarlosPando If this answers your question mark it as correct to close the question.

Comment: You've still got `"` in the first call to `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
var mydiv="#cc-"+i;
    $("mydiv iframe").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('"#cc-' + i + ' iframe"').attr("src", $('"#cc-' + i + 'iframe"').attr("src"));
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Osama, I found this provides the same result as Tony's answer above.

Comment: Yes that is right I only use a variable so that the statement within the selector is easy to read and with less single and double quetos the two ways with the same result